# Is there a tool to simplify XAML/the visual tree (transforming XAML or a Silverlight control instance)?

Tags: silverlight, performance, xaml

Complex visual trees are nice when designing views as they allow you to create a structure in XAML closely matching the logical structure of what you are modeling. They are however not great for performance, using a lot of nested panels with layout such as grids will reduce performance when adding and rendering views.

Is there a tool that can "render" a XAML control, either at compile time, creating an equivalent but flat XAML file (given a specified size), or at runtime, doing the same thing given an instance of a control? Are there any other ways to accomplish a similar thing (other than setting the CacheMode)?

Comment: now this is a great question, and a great need for perf improvement! +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Essentially, as far as I know, the most efficient way to model any layout is to use a grid with a very large number of columns and rows. A Grid can achieve anything else you do in SL/WPF (supposedly), so your answer in terms of efficiency would be to nest less and use one large Grid.

Comment: Assuming you don't care about resizing your control, a single Canvas would likely be the most efficient way - but I don't want to maintain my views using canvases, I want something to translate to that representation for me.